# Sliding images one after the other

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="postBack">
<img id="slideshow" class="1" height="550px" style="left: 0px; width: 2000px; position: relative; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; float:left;" src="images/deskapple.png">
<img id="slideshow" class="2" height="550px" style="left: 2000px; width: 2000px; position: relative; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="images/less.png">
</div>
```

An image is at 0px left, and the other should be after it at 2000px from the left, now I'm animating the first class 1 to left -2000px, and animating class 2 to 0px from the left. - But the class 2 is not visible.

```
        $("." + currentImage).animate({left: -2000 + "px"}, 1000);
        currentImage += 1;
        $("." + currentImage).animate({left: 0 + "px"}, 1000);
```

Comment: Create jsfiddle if possible, with a demo.

Comment: please refresh your question, couldn't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: I want the two imgs to be next to each other like so:

http://www.google.com.mt/imgres?imgurl=&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F25534174&h=0&w=0&tbnid=PlT3N47rXS8bpM&zoom=1&tbnh=168&tbnw=299&docid=BFIYn5Z081t44M&tbm=isch&client=firefox-a&ei=Fpg6U9XbC4OytAaxnoH4Dw&ved=0CBEQsCUoBQ

Then when I animate the first one to the left (which gets hidden) I animate the second to become visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

HTML:

```
<div class="postBack">
<img id="slideshow" class="1" height="550px" style="left: 0px; width: 2000px;
position: relative; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;
margin: 0px; float:left;" src="images/deskapple.png" >

<img id="slideshow" class="2" height="550px" style="left: 2000px; width: 2000px;
position: absolute; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; 
margin: 0px;" src="images/less.png">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var currentImage=1;

$("." + currentImage).animate({left: -2000 + "px"}, 1000);
    currentImage += 1;
    $("." + currentImage).animate({left: 0 + "px"}, 1000);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3htMG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use animate callback like this.

```
$("." + currentImage).stop().animate({left: "-2000px"}, 1000 , function() { 

        currentImage += 1;

        $("." + currentImage).stop().animate({left: "0px"}, 1000);
});
```